# GNU parallel escaped space of quoted arguments and python failed to parse the flags

Tags: python, gnu-parallel

i want to run
`parallel "python test.py --flag1 {}" ::: '--flag2 --flag3' '--flag4  --flag5'`
but my python failed to parse the flags and execute

when i try to dry run, the output is

```
python test.py --flag1 --flag2\ --flag3
python test.py --flag1 --flag4\ --flag5
```

how can i make parallel not escape my space betweem flags? e.g. `python test.py --flag1 --flag2 --flag3` without the escape character

almost tried all relevant search results e.g. `eval`, `-q`, but they seem unable to solve this, many thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could click `edit` under your question and give an indication of what you were hoping it would run.

Comment: thanks for suggesting! edited

Comment: No, ignore the `parallel` part completely. What 4 /6/8 Python scripts do you want to run and with what parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallel version < 20190722:

```
parallel eval python test.py --flag1 {} ::: '--flag2 --flag3' '--flag4  --flag5'
```

Parallel version >= 20190722:

```
parallel python test.py --flag1 {=uq=} ::: '--flag2 --flag3' '--flag4  --flag5'
```